# Rebound affecting Return to Dust (second main phase)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The way [Return to Dust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReturn%20to%20Dust%5d) is phrased is a bit confusing, does it see a difference between pre-combat and post combat main phases?  If I cast return to dust post combat and [Taigam, Ojutai Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTaigam%2c%20Ojutai%20Master%5d) is under my control, will I have 2 targets to choose from on the initial cast?  When the spell rebounds, will I have one or two targets available to me?

Answer (score 2):

**No, Return to Dust does not differentiate between pre- and post-combat main phases. You get to exile 1-2 targets when you cast it during any of your main phases, and 1 otherwise.**

Generally, when an effect asks about any property of an object or the game state (such as which phase it is), then as long as the wanted properties are fulfilled, the others can be what they want. Specifically, if Return to Dust does something else "if you cast it during your main phase", then it doesn't matter if it's your pre- or any post-combat main phase.

> 505.1. There are two main phases in a turn. In each turn, the first main phase (also known as the precombat main phase) and the second main phase (also known as the postcombat main phase) are separated by the combat phase (see rule 506, “Combat Phase”). **The precombat and postcombat main phases are individually and collectively known as the main phase.**

If you cast the card again through Rebound, it will happen during your upkeep. The second cast is independent of the previous because it's a new object rather than a copy, so it looks at the current phase. It finds that it's not a main phase, so you get to exile only 1 target.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.[..]

Comment: Technically, you can choose 2 targets if it's not your main phase, you just can't exile.